# javacpp in eclipse doesn't work --ClassNotFoundException (using JNI)

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, java-native-interface

I'm trying to use javacpp and encounter some difficulties with eclipse (+ mac OS).

When I run this in my command line - **it works fine**:

```
#include <string>

namespace LegacyLibrary {
    class LegacyClass {
        public:
            const std::string& getProperty() { return property; }
            void setProperty(const std::string& property) { this->property = property; }
        private:
            std::string property;
    };
}
```

and

```
import com.googlecode.javacpp.*;
import com.googlecode.javacpp.annotation.*;

@Platform(include="LegacyLibrary.h")
@Namespace("LegacyLibrary")
public class LegacyLibrary {
public static class LegacyClass extends Pointer {
    static { Loader.load(); }
    public LegacyClass() { allocate(); }
    private native void allocate();

    public native @ByRef String getProperty();
    public native void setProperty(String property);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LegacyClass l = new LegacyClass();
    l.setProperty("Hello World!");
    System.out.println(l.getProperty());
}
```

}

as suggested in [this](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/) post

I get the end result: "hello world".

Now I'm taking this into my eclipse IDE and for some reason, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.LegacyLibrary
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:293)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:271)
    at com.test.LegacyLibrary$LegacyClass.<clinit>(LegacyLibrary.java:12)
    at com.test.LegacyLibrary.main(LegacyLibrary.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.LegacyLibrary
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Launcher.java:229)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:291)
    ... 3 more
```

I placed the 2 files into a package com.test and the javacpp.jar I placed in the classpath. 
Is there anything I'm missing here?!?! the error message indicates that something in the classpath is incorrect (or missing), but what is it? (I also tried to point in the properties to the javacpp.jar in a different folder but I get the same error message). Maybe VM arguments?!?!

Thank you!

Comment: Note that `com.test.LegacyLibrary` is not the same class as `LegacyLibrary` in the default package. Did you rerun JavaCPP's Builder to get a fresh native library for this new class as well?

Comment: no, I didn't. If you get it - let me know

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the javacpp.jar file to the projects libraries? Go to the project properties, then the Build Path information, there should be a tab for Libraries. Add an External Jar file, and select the javacpp.jar file.

[image]

Comment: I tried this already (I wrote in the question, that I also added the javacpp.jar via the project properties). Same error message.

Comment: Do you find any solution?? I have the same problem now

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project Properties->Java Build Path, in the tab Source click on the arrow to expand the source folder, then select Native Library Location and click on Edit, After all find the path to the LegacyLibrary.h file and that should work.

[image: Add native library to Eclipse project]

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your maven file is misconfigured and hence gcc compiler cannot find your source file `LegacyLibrary.h`.

Configure your pom.xml using the following link as a reference.

https://github.com/oltzen/JavaCppExample/blob/master/pom.xml

Pay attention to line 53 and 65. Fill in the correct package names. This helps the compiler find out where your `LegacyLibrary.h` is.

Also, watch this video clip https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LZrrqZLhtmw which walks you through the whole process how to run Javacpp with maven and eclipse.